# What is a vim regex for "abcd", where "bc" is optional?

Tags: regex, vim

I want to search for occurrences of `ad` and `abcd` where the `bc` is optional.  How can I do that?  i.e.,

```
+-------+----------+
| ad    | MATCH    |
| abcd  | MATCH    |
| abd   | NO match |
| abbd  | NO match |
| abced | NO match |
| abcbcd| NO match |
+-------+----------+
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Solutions:
option 1: `ad\|abcd`
option 2: `a\(bc\)\=d`
option 3: `a\(bc\)\?d`
option 4: `\va%[(bc)]d`
option 5: `a\%[\(bc\)]d`

Close but not quite:
`a\(bc\)\{-\}d`
(zero or **more**; matches **abcbcd** which is not desired)

```
+--------+--------------------------+---------------+
| syntax | description              | documentation |
+--------+--------------------------+---------------|
| \|     | logical OR (alternation) | :help /\|     |
| \(bc\) | treat `bc` as a group    | :help /atom   |
| \=     | zero or one occurrences  | :help \=      |
| \?     | zero or one occurrences  | :help \?      |
| \{-\}  | zero or more occurrences |               |
| \%[]   | make the match optional  | :help \%[]    |
| \v     | "very magic": omit \'s   | :help \v      |
+--------+--------------------------+---------------+
```

Comment: What?,, why did you post an question if you know answer ? I am **not** down voter!

Comment: [http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) @GrijeshChauhan

Comment: This answer is not correct: option 1, `a\(bc\)\?d`, is a correct answer, but option 2, `a\(bc\)\{-\}` matches 0 or more occurrences of `bc`. The correct option 2 is `a\(bc\)\=d`.

Comment: My Vim 7.4 help says: `\?    Just like \=. ...`. So `\?` is actually a correct answer, I think.

Comment: Closing curly braces in quantifiers does NOT need escaping backslash, so intead of `a\(bc\)\{-\}d` it should be `a\(bc\)\{-}d` in the not quite match!

Answer (score 8):

`/ad\|abcd`

[`\|` is logical OR (alternation)]

Comment: +1; From a _VimGolf_ perspective (i.e. fewest keystrokes) you're right. The outcome counts most, after all!

Comment: Yes, I like that better.  Thanks @Kent!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option where "bc" is optional.

`\va%[(bc)]d`

Without the `\v` ("very magic"):

`a\%[\(bc\)]d`

**Explanation:**
`\%[]` makes a match optional.
`\(bc\)` groups "bc".
`\v` (very magic) at the beginning allows you to omit the backslash `\`.